# Magento 2 what happen if a block doesn't define a template path in layout

Tags: magento2, blocks, template

In Magento 2 ,`layout files` i see some blocks doesn't specify a template. So `which template it will use`?

Comment: Can u please tell me for whic?h blocks you did not find template s

Comment: for example in [code]<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">189</argument>
                        <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>[/code] in /home/pnguyen/LEARNING/magento2/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mentioned some block so I have taken random example for you

Look block alone declaration in `app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
```

check that block file (**Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs**), inside they set templates for the block

**app/code/Magento/Theme/Block/Html/Breadcrumbs.php**

```
protected $_template = 'html/breadcrumbs.phtml';
```

**template file location :** `app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/breadcrumbs.phtml`

Comment: Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo also same concept